# Image Resize without stretching and shrinking

Tags: go

I am using [https://github.com/nfnt/resize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GykQG.png) to resize image

```
// open "test.jpg"
file, err := os.Open("images/" + fileName)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

// decode jpeg into image.Image
img, err := jpeg.Decode(file)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
file.Close()


m := resize.Resize(500, 500, img, resize.Lanczos3)

out, err := os.Create("images/" + fileName + "_resized.jpg")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer out.Close()

// write new image to file
jpeg.Encode(out, m, nil)
```

That gives me the output like:

[image: [1]: https://github.com/nfnt/resize]

I don't want to stretch the image, Just want to resize and fill white background in the added area. Don't have any idea with Go. In Laravel i done with the help of http://image.intervention.io But don't have idea with GO lang. Please help me to achieve this.

Comment: you're not resizing the image, you're wanting to resize the *canvas*

Comment: @Martin exactly, does the same library helps me to achieve this?

Comment: The library you've chosen is specifically for image resizing. If you only need to resize the underlying canvas - you don't need additional libraries, the standard library is suffice.

Comment: You can have a look at [nuggan](https://github.com/cchantep/nuggan) (I'm a contributor of)

Answer (score 0):

You can use another function from the same library:

`resize.Thumbnail` downscales an image **preserving its aspect ratio** to the maximum dimensions